# How to draw polygons from the python console?

Tags: python, geometry, qgis-2

I've been visiting and revisiting the page on geometry handling in the PyQGIS Cookbook: http://documentation.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html but can't seem to figure out how to get the polygon to draw from the Python console. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

it is not realy complicated, look at **Memory provider** in [vector](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html): :

- a point is created with `QgsPoint(x,y)` and `QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y))`
- a line is created with two points: `QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(x1,y1),QgsPoint(x2,y2)]))`
- a polygon is created with a list of points: `QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([[QgsPoint(x1,y1),QgsPoint(x2,y2), QgsPoint(x3,y3)]])`

1) two points:

```
# create a memory layer with two points
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider() 
# add the first point
pt = QgsFeature()
point1 = QgsPoint(50,50)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()
# add the second point
pt = QgsFeature()
point2 = QgsPoint(100,150)
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point2))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent
layer.updateExtents()
# add the layer to the canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

[image]

2) the line connecting the two points

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('LineString', 'line' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider() 
line = QgsFeature()
line.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([point1,point2]))
pr.addFeatures([line])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

[image]

3) a polygon covering the points

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'poly' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider() 
poly = QgsFeature()
points = [point1,QgsPoint(50,150),point2,QgsPoint(100,50)]
# or points = [QgsPoint(50,50),QgsPoint(50,150),QgsPoint(100,150),QgsPoint(100,50)] 
poly.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
pr.addFeatures([poly])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

[image]

-

**Changes in QGIS 3.0 and onward:**

For QGIS 3.0 and onward the above workflow is still correct, but certain functions have changed. See https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

To update the above code, change following functions:

```
QgsPoint -> QgsPointXY
QgsfromPoint -> QgsfromPointXY
QgsfromPolyline -> QgsfromPolylineXY
QgsfromPolygon -> QgsfromPolylineXY
QgsfromPolyline -> QgsfromPolylineXY
QgsMapLayerRegistry -> QgsProject
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code.  I was wondering how can I get rid of CRS selection dialog after I run the code?

Comment: how can I add style?

Comment: That update was extremely useful for me -couldn't seem to find it in the documentation- I've used this answer several times now for my tools. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Just select the CRS in the layer definition : 
`QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:2154', 'poly' , "memory")` for instance (here EPSG 2154 is for Lambert 93 projection, standard in Metropolitan France, but you can put whatever you want)

Comment: how can i add style?