# make polygon by points with python

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, point

I have an excel file with x and y. how can I use this excel file in qgis' python console as point vector layer to make polygon with all the points in the file.(it is important for me to use python)

Comment: Can you clarify more, you want to create one polygon from all points in the excel file ? and do you want it specially with python or you are okay to use QGIS features to import the file ?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to draw polygons from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86812/how-to-draw-polygons-from-the-python-console)

Comment: I saw this document before, but my problem is how to read the points from an external file, and not adding the points manually.?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include a sample screen shot of what your excel/data looks like so we can see the structure?

Comment: just imagine we have a closed line like this:
[-76.515681 95.210066;
-76.216625 87.733669;
-77.113793 78.462936;
-77.113793 71.734179;
-76.814737 61.715806;
-64.104862 46.314428;
-63.955334 59.921471;
-63.805806 66.799756;
-63.506750 71.883707;
-62.759110 77.864825;
-62.609582 83.845942;
-62.908638 91.770924;
-66.945893 95.509122;
-76.515681 95.210066]

Comment: Joseph's comment shows you a way how to do it, and parsing CSV or XLS is rather StackOverflow question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQGIS supports delimited files including CSV.  For example in the QGIS Python Console you could do the following:

```
uri = "file:///C:/data/points.csv?type=csv&xField=x&yField=y&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no"

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'My Points', "delimitedtext")
```

Just replace the xField and yField variables with the x,y column names in your CSV.