# Build a QGIS plugin to convert XY coordinates to a polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-plugins, coordinates, csv

I've been trying to create a plugin in QGIS that browse an excel sheet containing XY coordinates (points) and convert them (automatically) to a shapefile (polygon on this case). If done manually, I would add the data from the CSV file and link the points one by one to get a polygon. But am trying to automate this procedure for the users by creating this plugin.

My first question would be : is this even possible ? 
If so, can someone please indicate how it could be done, expecially the python code that can be used.

Answer (score 5):

You load the points into a list and create the polygon from the list of points:

```
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'polygon' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider() 
polygon = QgsFeature()
points = [QgsPoint(50,50),QgsPoint(50,150),QgsPoint(100,150)] 
polygon.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([points]))
pr.addFeatures([polygon])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

I found the code here by the way: [How to draw polygons from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86812/how-to-draw-polygons-from-the-python-console)

The list 'points' can be created in a loop by appending

```
QgsPoint(x,y)
```

to the list for all x,y in the spreadsheet.