# Creating polygon out of list of points QgsPointXY

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, polygon-creation

I am attempting to create a simple polygon on QGIS 3.14 using PyQGIS by adapting the code from [How to draw polygons from the python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86812).

I am running into an error with the `setGeometry` line where the function `fromPolylineXY` appears to need a `QgsPointXY` object but the `pts` object is a list.

Code so far is listed below.

```py
tmp = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsg:29194', '200905_Bdy',"org") #Layer for polygon 
prv = tmp.dataProvider()                               #Data object for polygon layer
ply01 = QgsFeature()                                   #Object for polygon
# Object with polygon verticies
pts = [QgsPointXY(396100,8969000),QgsPointXY(396100,8973900),QgsPointXY(397900,8973900),QgsPointXY(397900,8969000)]
ply01.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([pts]))
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `fromPolygonXY` instead of `fromPolylineXY` to create a polygon.
Use `ply01.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts]))`

If you want to create a polyline before creating a polygon, you should know this: `pts` object is a list. And `fromPolylineXY` expects "a list of `QgsPointXY`". When you use extra brackets like `[pts]`, it will be a list of list of `QgsPointXY` (`[[QgsPointXY, QgsPointXY, ...]]`).
To create o polyline you should remove the bracket in `fromPolylineXY([pts])` to get a list of `QgsPointXY`. Just use `fromPolylineXY(pts)`.

Briefly;
To create a polygon from point list: `QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([pts])`
To create a polyline from point list: `QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY(pts)`

Comment: Kadir, thank you for you your response which has solved my issue. I'm assuming the use of square brackets to make a list is python code convention? Or is it something unique to pyQGIS - as you can probably guess I'm new to both

Comment: Yes. It is a python rule.